# what value the this.id returns?

Tags: html

I want to know what value  holds in `this.id`.

```
<input id='edit" + id + "' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />"
```

The button calls edit().
So, shall i write `var newid = id;` to get the ID value of edit button.

Thanks

Comment: That will error. Attribute values must be quoted in XHTML, and (if they include a `(` character) also in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets you the ***value*** of the `id` attribute eg `id='edit" + id + "'`.

Comment: @MaRaVaN: Exactly :) So you are basically passing the id value to the edit function.

Comment: Don mistake me, i am a noob in this. What arg i should pass to edit().
Shall it look like edit(id){var newid = id;}

Comment: @MaRaVaN: Yes that's looks fine.

Comment: @Sarfraz: It WORKS DUDE... Great MaN... I spent almost 1 hour in this. Thank you very much man. Thank you very much.